# fetch the array of object based on property same using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two array of objects,`arr1` and `arr2`

if `taskId` and `id` same then retreive from `arr1`

How to check based on property from arr1 and arr2 in javascript

```
var arr1= [
  {"name":"refresh task","memberIds":[981],"dueOn":"2022-08-30","taskId":19},
  {"name":"ref one","memberIds":[981,982],"dueOn":"2022-08-25","taskId":null}
]

var arr2 =[
{
"country": "IN", 
"tasks": [
    {id: 19, "name": "abc" },
    {id: 20, "name": "xyz" }
  ]
}
]
I tried 
var result = arr1.filter(e=>e.taskId===(arr2.map(i=>i.tasks.map(t=>t.id))

Expected Output
[
  {"name":"refresh task","memberIds":[981],"dueOn":"2022-08-30","taskId":19}
]
```

Comment: do a flatMap+map on arr2 to get a list of id. after that do a filter on arr1 and check if each element is include in the id list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), and `[`Array#map`][3], get the list of task ids in` arr2``
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has), return the resulting array where `taskId` is in the above set

```js
const
  arr1= [
    {"name":"refresh task", "memberIds":[981], "dueOn":"2022-08-30", "taskId":19},
    {"name":"ref one", "memberIds":[981,982], "dueOn":"2022-08-25", "taskId":null}
  ],
  arr2 =[
    { 
      "country": "IN", 
      "tasks": [ {"id": 19, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 20, "name": "xyz"} ]
    }
  ];

const taskIdSet = new Set(
  arr2.flatMap(({ tasks = [] }) => tasks.map(({ id }) => id))
);
const result = arr1.filter(({ taskId }) => taskIdSet.has(taskId));

console.log(result);
```

EDIT:
To get "I have two arrays of objects, arr1, and arr2 if taskId and id not same then retrieve from arr2":

```js
const
  arr1= [
    {"name":"refresh task", "memberIds":[981], "dueOn":"2022-08-30", "taskId":19},
    {"name":"ref one", "memberIds":[981,982], "dueOn":"2022-08-25", "taskId":null}
  ],
  arr2 =[
    { 
      "country": "IN", 
      "tasks": [ {"id": 19, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 20, "name": "xyz"} ]
    }
  ];

const taskIdSet = arr1.reduce((taskIdSet, { taskId }) => {
  if(taskId !== null) { taskIdSet.add(taskId); }
  return taskIdSet;
}, new Set);
const result = arr2
  .flatMap(({ tasks = [] }) => tasks)
  .filter(({ id }) => !taskIdSet.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, if i want get arr2 that are not matching with arr1 taskId , i.e(arr2 with no null and not same taskid and id)

Comment: @can help how to do

Comment: ```I have two array of objects,arr1 and arr2
if taskId and id not same then retreive from arr2```  Expected Output
[
  {id: 20, "name": "xyz" }
]

Comment: @codelearn in this case, you need to save non-null task ids from arr1 in a set and do the filter on arr2

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
var result = arr1.filter(e=>{
    for(let obj of arr2){ 
      for(let task of obj.tasks){
        return e.taskId === task.id; 
        }
    }
 })
```